# looking for a way/function to kill/delete alll whitespace/empty area in a region to start of line

Tags: text-editing

im looking for a way/function to kill/delete alll whitespace/empty area in a region to start of line. for example if i have this snippet

```
(defhydra hydra-copy-paste  (:color blue  :columns 4 :hints nil)
  "copy paste operations"
     ("0" z/copy-buffer-file-path  "copy current buffer to path" )
("a" align-regexp "align-regexp" )
  ("c" copy-to-register  "copy to register") 
("e" hydra-edit-extra/body  "Extra editing commands" :face 'hydra-face-purple)

    ("d" downcase-region  "downcase " )
("p" insert-register  "paste from register") 
("v" view-register  "view register") 
    ("r" z/open-this-file-as-other-user  "edit as root" :face 'hydra-face-red )
    ("u" upcase-region  "upcase " )
("q" nil "cancel" nil)
)
```

i want it to run and format the section by killing all whitespace till start of line so it looks like this

```
(defhydra hydra-copy-paste  (:color blue  :columns 4 :hints nil)
"copy paste operations"
("0" z/copy-buffer-file-path  "copy current buffer to path" )
("a" align-regexp "align-regexp" )
("c" copy-to-register  "copy to register") 
("e" hydra-edit-extra/body  "Extra editing commands" :face 'hydra-face-purple)
("d" downcase-region  "downcase " )
("p" insert-register  "paste from register") 
("v" view-register  "view register") 
("r" z/open-this-file-as-other-user  "edit as root" :face 'hydra-face-red )
("u" upcase-region  "upcase " )
("q" nil "cancel" nil)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to look at the implementation of `(delete-trailing-whitespace)`, but certainly, the easiest way would be to select the region and hit:

`M-x replace-regexp RET ^[[:space:]]+ RET RET`

You can bundle that into an interactive function if need be.

Comment: thx thats perfect!

Comment: actually, i created this small little function ```(defun zxx  ()
"delete all numeric characters"
(interactive)
(goto-char (point-min))
(replace-regexp "^[[:space:]]+" "")
)```. this works well. any idea how to make the above funtion work only on marked region?

Comment: `replace-regexp` accepts args for the start and end positions of its application. You can pick up the region limits with `(interactive "r")`, and test whether the region is active and non-empty with `use-region-p`.